# docker dumb-init crashes on startup

Tags: docker

I am trying to launch a Docker container but crashes instantly.  I look at the logs,  and the run.sh that is defined in the Docker file as the ENTRYPOINT. So I tried to pin down the line in the script that was failing, and kept chipping away at the code, until I have this: (this is the whole run.sh right now)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/dumb-init /bin/bash
echo "Starting Run Script"
```

To me, I think I have one line in this script,  to echo "Starting Run Script" How does that throw a No such file error?

the dumb-init binary is where it's supposed to be. I go to interactive mode like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh myimage:latest
```

And I run the script manually in the container,  and I get this error message:

```
: No such file or directory
```

But with the dumb-init being binary code,  I have no idea what file/folder it's looking for.  Is there a config or properties file somewhere?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/dumb-init` exist in the container?  In a non-interactive mode, bash without a script will just terminate. The `echo` in the script is passed to `dumb-init`. Its unclear if that will pass through to `bash`.

Comment: @danblack  That was the first thing I checked.  But what, exactly, is it looking for?  That is the whole script.  All i do is "echo" something.  How does that turn into No such file error?

Comment: what is your docker image ? btw did `docker run -it yourimage bash` is working ?

Answer (score 0):

I donno if you still need this, but you need to install dumb-init when creating your docker image
RUN apk add dumb-init
in your dockerfile